# Laravel and MySQL understanding Index and composite/compound index

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

In Laravel (v 6.8) I have created below migration for the `users` table.

## User Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique()->index();
        $table->string('email')->unique()->index();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->enum('role', ['super', 'admin', 'manager', 'subscriber', 'user'])->default('user');
        $table->boolean('is_root')->default(FALSE);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['username', 'email'], 'user_unique_credentials');
        $table->index(['username', 'email'], 'user_index_columns');
    });
}
```

#### Explaination

I know basics of `index` and how it works but I a having not so clear understanding about `index` on individual `column` and `composite/compound` `index`.

The App may have query by only `username` or `email` or I may have a query for both tables together. Therefore as you can see in my migration code, I have set `index` for each column as well as both columns using `$this->index()` that creates a `compound` `index`.

> #### Question
>
> I want to know if I have set all the `indexes` correctly or it is a bad idea to set up the way I did?
>
> **If it is not correct then may I know the correct way to do it?**

Comment: I assume `username` and `email` are individually unique. rather than the `username`,`email` pair being individually unique. As such each should be a single unique. Seems specifying this as an index as well is redundant as MySQL will make a unque index to enforce the uniqueness ( less sure on this - don't know Laravel that well - having it create duplicate indexes is waste).

Comment: Since I get any reply, I began testing myself, and I realized the same as you said. Creating a `unique` key `MySQL` creates an `index` for it. So, in that case, no need to create a separate `index.` Now the query remains in my mind is should I make a compound `unique` or on an individual column since I have to check uniqueness on both together or individual uniqueness. As far as I understood, I need to apply for individuals as well as compound. But need experts guidance.

Answer (score 2):

[@danblack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10195153/danblack) thanks for your help.

Okay so trying with `EXPLAIN`query with various way setting up `unique` and `index` finally, I found the final version as below.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create(
        'users',
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->enum('role', ['super', 'admin', 'manager', 'subscriber', 'user'])->default('user');
            $table->boolean('is_root')->default(FALSE);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique(['username', 'email'], 'users_unique_credentials');
        }
    );
}
```

This way when we query on individual column, it will use own unique index. When we search with both columns with multiple `WHERE` clause it will use the `compound` `unique` index.

Comment: There isn't a strong need for a compound index. if you search for both, mysql will look at one of the indexs, and if there' s a record found, the second value can be verified quite quickly. If will be (unnoticeably) slower if the existence of the pair is the only part of the query, any additional query criteria or fetched fields like `is_root` will result in exactly the same query time. Thanks for the join work to make this answer.

Comment: @danblack thanks a lot for your input. Sorry, not mentioning your help in answer. I will update it.